# GitHub でWebサービスを公開しようとしたが、button onclick が動かない。

Tags: github, github-pages

WebサービスをGitHubで公開しようと思い、下記のURLを２つ習得しました。

- https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/food.quiz/ （以下、quiz）
- https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/food.quiz.question/ （以下、question）

上のURLから下のURLに移動するため、quizのHTMLには、以下のコードを書きましたが、ページの移動ができません。

```html
<div class = "dis">
    <button type="button" onclick="location.href='https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/food.quiz.question/'">料理を表示させる！</button>
</div>
```

quiz は "HTML, CSS"、question は "HTML, CSS, JavaScript" で構成されています。
ご回答、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ためしに、ローカルで `<html><body><div class = "dis"><button type="button" onclick="location.href='https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/food.quiz.question/'">料理を表示させる！</button></body></html>` と書いてみたところ、画面が遷移されました。GitHubに置いたからといって影響を受けるとは思えないので、他になにか影響を与えるものに覚えはありませんか？

Comment: 実際、https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/food.quiz/　にアクセスして「料理を表示させる！」をボタンをクリックしたところ、https://nayuta-ichino.github.io/food.quiz.question/ に遷移できていますよ。

Comment: ご回答いただき誠にありがとうございます。ご指摘後も正常に動作しなかったため、別端末で試したところ正常に動きました。もしかしたらと思いPCを再起動してみたら滞りなく動くようになりました。

Comment: キャッシュかなにかが残っていたのかもしれませんね

Answer (score 1, accepted):

別端末で試したところ正常に動きました。もしかしたらと思い、PCを再起動してみたら滞りなく動くようになりました。

ご回答いただいた方、また時間を割いてこの質問を見てくださった方、誠にありがとうございました。